Deducing const template argument from mutable alternative
When a function takes a std::span of const T, it cannot deduce the span type from a mutable span that is being passed in.
Is it however possible for a user-defined type to allow the deductionn of the const alternative from the mutable alternative (maybe through the help of deduction guides)?
template<typename T>
struct MySpan
{};

template<typename T>
void takingConst(std::span<const T>)
{}
template<typename T>
void takingMyConst(MySpan<const T>)
{}

int square(int num) 
{
    std::span<int> stdSpan{};
    takingConst(std::span<const int>(stdSpan));

    MySpan<int> mySpan{};
    takingMyConst(mySpan); //Any way to make this work?
}


https://godbolt.org/z/nEeKP4n3W

Always post complete error along with your question.

Make the non-const MySpan<T> inherit from MySpan<const T>.
Here's a way that is easy to understand:
template<typename T>
struct MySpan : public MySpan<const T> {
    MySpan() = default;
    MySpan(T* ptr, std::size_t size) : MySpan<const T>(ptr, size) {}
    T* data() const { return const_cast<T*>(MySpan<const T>::data()); }
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data()[i]; }
    using MySpan<const T>::size;
};

template<typename T>
struct MySpan<const T> {
    MySpan() = default;
    MySpan(const T* ptr, std::size_t size) : ptr(ptr), sz(size) {}
    const T* data() const { return ptr; }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data()[i]; }
    std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
private:
    const T* ptr = nullptr;
    std::size_t sz = 0;
};

Here's a way that doesn't duplicate code:
template<typename T>
struct MySpan;

namespace detail {
    template<typename T>
    struct my_span_members {
    private:
        T* ptr = nullptr;
        std::size_t sz = 0;
        template<typename>
        friend struct ::MySpan;
    };
}

template<typename T>
struct MySpan : std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, detail::my_span_members<T>, MySpan<const T>> {
private:
    using base = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<T>, detail::my_span_members<T>, MySpan<const T>>;
public:
    MySpan() = default;
    MySpan(T* ptr, std::size_t size) : base{ static_cast<const T*>(ptr), size } {}
    template<std::size_t N>
    MySpan(std::type_identity_t<T>(& arr)[N]) : MySpan(arr, N) {}
    // ...
    T* data() const { return const_cast<T*>(base::ptr); }
    std::size_t size() const { return base::sz; }

    T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return data()[i]; }
    // ...
};


Doesn't the const_cast cause undefined behaviour here? Or it doesn't because it is only const_cast when it is initialized from pointer to mutable T?

@AndreasLoanjoe const_cast only changes the type when T is mutable (the pointer stored is always a pointer to a const object), and when T is mutable the constructor takes a mutable pointer. Also const_cast on its own never causes UB, only if you try to modify something where const_cast removed a const but it was actually const.
